# PowerShell Send-Mailmessage In Task Scheduler

Tags: powershell

We have a couple of PowerShell scripts where we use the Send-Mailmessage command to send emails. We have been running these scripts from Task Scheduler for over a year now and just last week the emails stopped going out. The rest of the script is working fine. If I run from within PowerShell the email goes out.

I've tried on a couple of different computers (Windows Server 2008 and 2012R2 with the same results. Nothing is showing up in the Event Viewer indicating a failure. Thoughts on what to check?

Comment: Are you running the script from the same context as task scheduler is running it? Has your mail admin changed authentication options for smtp?

Comment: Yes to the first question and no to the second.

Comment: Try adding `start-transcript` to the top of the script and review the transcript file so you can see if it throws an error when run via the scheduler.

Comment: I found out the task wasn't running from the same context as I was running the script, my mistake. We had a support vendor patch our Exchange server a couple of weeks, about the time this started to happen. Before the schedule task was running under the SYSTEM account. Whatever patch was applied caused this to stop working. I changed it to a domain account with the proper access and it appears to be working now. I will know for sure tomorrow.

Comment: What it turned out to be was the task was using the SYSTEM account to run, which it has for almost two years now. Our support vendor applied patches to our Exchange 2013 to bring it up to date and emails stopped working after that. Using a domain account that has permissions for email to run the tasks "resolved" the issue for us. I would like to find out what patch/hot fix caused this issue.